# Use name of Excel workbook/file in SQL data source query

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, excel, ms-office

I have a SQL Server database and users want approx. 300 different Excel files to use as reports, each with a slightly different SQL query (I'm sure there's a better solution to this, but that's the ask!).

Essentially

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE MyValue = XXXX
```

Each Excel file has a different pre-determined `MyValue`.

I know I can generate the 300 Excel files through C#. My idea for the query is to have `MyValue` in the Excel filename and use it as a variable in the SQL statement.

How can I achieve having the filename in as `MyValue`? Either through part of my file generation in C# or a VBA script that creates the data source gets applied to each file.

Comment: Excel files aren't tables. The *easy* solution is to use a NuGet package like EPPlus, ClosedXML or one of the many other Excel creation libraries, to generate actual Excel files from query results, without ever installing Excel or having to use the Access driver. Most of them can work with existing files as templates, allow multiple sheets, styling and even formulas (up to a point)

Comment: With eg EPPlus loading query results into a sheet, with table headers, is as easy as `var tableRange=sheet.Cells.LoadFromDataReader(reader,true, TableStyles.Dark1);`

Comment: The name of the workbook is in the connection string.  The connection string is a string and you can change the name of the workbook in the connection string.

Comment: Why not pass the file name as a parameter to the query? Even better, why not store all 300 values to a "settings" table and create both the file name and the query values from that setting?

Answer (score 2):

The question is unclear. It seems the requirement is to export data into 300 different Excel files based on a parameter that comes from .... somewhere. That parameter also affects the file name somehow.

Assuming we have a list with those parameters somewhere, we could use a library like [EPPlus](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus) or [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Copying-IEnumerable-Collections) to generate Excel files [directly from query results](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus/wiki/LoadFromDataReader), eg :

```
public void ExportReport(string theValue,string connectionString)
{
    var sql="SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyValue = @theValue";
    using var con=new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    using var reader=con.ExecuteReader(sql,new {theValue=theValue});

    using var package = new ExcelPackage();
    var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
    sheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataReader(reader, true,TableStyles.Dark1);

    var excelPath=CalculatePathFromValue(root,theValue);
    package.SaveAs(new FileInfo(excelpath));
}
```

The example uses [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/tree/ff913be39109a1fdac9caa5a32ff3d32d9acb2a0) to get rid of the boilerplate code needed to construct parameterized commands and pass parameter values. Dapper can also map results directly to a list of items. EPPlus (and other libraries can work with IEnumerable data too:

```
public void ExportReport(string theValue,string connectionString)
{
    var sql="SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyValue = @theValue";
    using var con=new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    using var orders=con.Query<Order>(sql,new {theValue=theValue});

    using var package = new ExcelPackage();
    var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
    sheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(orders, true,TableStyles.Dark1);

    var excelPath=CalculatePathFromValue(root,theValue);
    package.SaveAs(new FileInfo(excelpath));
}
```